# chart legend title was same in line series ,the title not repeated

Tags: charts

```
<apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="property0" strokeColor="#B22222" strokeWidth="1" 
             markerType="circle" markerSize="2" markerFill="#B22222"  title="{!stagenameslist}" />

<apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="name" yField="property1" strokeColor="#B22222" strokeWidth="1" 
             markerType="circle" markerSize="2" markerFill="#00FFFF" title="{!stagenameslist}"  />
```

Page Controller:

```
public List<String> lstProperties {
    get {
          List<String> lstProperties = new List<String>();
           List<RMProperty__c > propertylist=new List<RMProperty__c >();
                  propertylist = [Select id, name  From   RMProperty__c  where Active__c=true
                                                          order by name asc];

             if(propertylist != null && propertylist.size() > 0){         
                    for (RMProperty__c  prop: propertylist) {
                        lstProperties.add(prop.name);
                    } 
                } 

        return lstProperties;    
    }
}                                   

public String stagenameslist {
    get {           
        return String.join(lstProperties, ',');
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have posted the same question before as well. [Title Worked fine in apex:Barseries ,but not worked in apex:line series,](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93646/title-worked-fine-in-apexbarseries-but-not-worked-in-apexline-series). That one looks detailed. Is that the same problem

Comment: Yes ,Can you please send the solution , how to fix this bug